# keep background image centered

Tags: jquery, css

Ok, so I am trying to mimic Googles homepage. What it seems is that even with small image Google stretches it to fit in and does not overfill it that much. I tried using background-position but it may look good for some image but looks like crap for others. So my question is how would I be able to pull this trick with the use of jQuery?

ok here is the css which i am using atm

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: auto;
background-clip: border-box;
background-origin: padding-box; 
background-attachment:scroll; 
background-position: 0px 28%;
position: fixed;
z-index:-10;
```

and div style in the page which uses css class above as its on style to display image in background

```
<div style="display: block; opacity: 0.99999; width: 1600px; height: auto; left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; background-image: url(<?php echo base64_decode($_COOKIE['phx_utmc_session']); ?>);" id="phx_utmc_background"></div>
```

There might be some problems with using width as height in the div portion but I am not sure since without height it wont work.

So ye ^^

Comment: Can you explain desired effect a bit? There's one image on google home page (logo) and it's always of the same size.

Comment: I am talking about custom background function on google

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, this can be accomplished with CSS

Try

```
body {
   background: url('http://placekitten.com/200/300');
   background-position: center 0%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[Live link](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/U4kUD/17/)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried just using CSS

```
body {
   background: url('background.png') no-repeat center right 40% 0 transparent;
}
```

Though I haven't tested that, it seems you could accomplish this with CSS.

Comment: Yep. I don't think you need jQuery for that, at all.

Comment: Your particular snippet is broken / does nothing. test it with a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).